# D3 Convention for (re)drawing a single object

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm using D3 to draw a custom graphs with a border rectangle around it.  On window resize, I recalculate the SVG size and want to redraw this border.  I'm currently doing this in a `drawGraph()` function which gets called on resize / new data:

```
...
svg.selectAll('rect')
     .data([true])
     .attr('width', w)
     .attr('height', h)
     .enter()
     .append('rect')
     .attr('x', 0)
     .attr('y', 0)
     .attr('width', w)
     .attr('height', h)
     .style('fill', 'none')
...
```

i.e. - I am binding a single value in an array (`[true]`) to the selection so that I can either draw the box, or just change its size if it's already been drawn once.  It certainly works, but it feels slightly odd to bind data which is guaranteed to be ignored, and possibly a slightly hacky way of doing things.

Is this a well-used convention, or is there another standard way of doing this, such as:

- A D3 method which I've not come across
- Just using `svg.append('rect')` and then removing + redrawing it on resize
- `svg.selectAll('*').remove()` and redrawing everything from scratch?
- Anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing and redrawing elements is what I call *lazy coding*  or *lazy update*  in D3.

That being said, why don't you simply assign the rectangle to a variable and change it on resize? Something like this (click "full page" and resize the window):

```js
var div = document.getElementById("div");
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var rect = svg.append("rect")//here you define your rectangle
  .attr("width", 300)
  .attr("height", 150)
  .attr("stroke-width", 3)
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("fill", "none");

function resize() {
  var width = div.clientWidth;

  svg.attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", width / 2);
  
  //here you just change its width and height
  rect.attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", width / 2);
}

window.addEventListener("resize", resize);
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: tan;
}
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="div">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```